# How to prevent launch shutdown on single remote connection failure? (required="true" not working)

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch set up that includes two separate other launch files which are run on other machines. Those launch files have nodes with attribute `required="true"` set however, the first node fails to start because of a failed ssh connection and the second is never attempted as the launch file exits on the first failure.

I suspect that the `required="true"` doesn't take effect as the remote ssh connection fails before hand, but the `machine` and `include` tags don't have a `required="true"` option.

Is there a way to prevent a remote machine launch failure from killing the entire launch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52130/how-to-prevent-launch-shutdown-on-single-remote-connection-failure?-(required=%22true%22-not-working)/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The required=True is for process management.  roslaunch does not have the functionality to continue through a lost link to the remote machine.

It would be a good feature request.  And as a work around if you use openvpn between the machines the connection will persist over a broken link if using the tunnel interface.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1